# Cannot run mysqldump in XAMPP

Tags: java

I am not able to do an mysqldump in xampp, it says "The system can not find the file specified". I'm using the following code:

```java
    public boolean backupDB(String dbName, String dbUserName, String dbPassword, String path) {

        String[] executeCmd = new String[] {
                "mysqldump.exe",
                "-u",
                dbUserName,
                "-p",
                dbPassword,
                "--add-drop-database",
                "-B",
                dbName,
                "-r",
                path
            };

        Process runtimeProcess;
        try {

            File pasta = new File("C:\\xampp\\mysql\\bin");
            runtimeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(executeCmd, null, pasta);
            int processComplete = runtimeProcess.waitFor();

            if (processComplete == 0) {
                System.out.println("Backup created successfully");
                return true;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Could not create the backup");
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return false;
    }
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

```java
    java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "mysqldump.exe" (in directory "C:\xampp\mysql\bin"): CreateProcess error=2, O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
        at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:620)
        at xd.test.backupDB(test.java:25)
        at xd.ee.main(ee.java:7)
```

Setting one is the mysqldump and it is the right type of extension, it still does not find mysqldump. I tried everything and could not solve this, any ideas?

Comment: Try setting the execute command to be "c:\\xamp\\mysql\\bin\\mysqldump.exe" rather than just the name.

Comment: i try but nothing, i make this here:         File pasta = new File("C:\\xampp\\mysql\\bin");
        runtimeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(executeCmd, null, pasta);

Comment: Just to be clear, rather than attempting to rely upon the working directory, you modified the `executeCmd` so that the full path to the mysqldump.exe was specified. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes I did this trying to solve the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a ProcessBuilder instead, try this:

```
String[] executeCmd = new String[] {
        "C:\\xampp\\mysql\\bin\\mysqldump.exe ",
        "-u ",
        dbUserName,
        "-p ",
        dbPassword,
        "--add-drop-database ",
        "-B ",
        dbName,
        "-r ",
        path
};

final ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(Arrays.asList(executeCmd));
final Process p;
try {
    p = pb.start();
    int processComplete = p.waitFor();

    if (processComplete == 0) {
        System.out.println("Backup created successfully");
        return true;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Could not create the backup");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
        String line = null;
        while ( (line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
} catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: ty bro not have error more but  not creating the file  debugging after this              "-B", in array dont go to : 
dbName,
    "-r",
    path

Comment: @CarlosMontana I cannot understand you, try to use a translator.

Comment: excuse
The method is not creating the file arraylist does not add this "-B",
    dbName,
    "-r",
    path
I'm not having an error, but it does not create the file

Comment: I do not know if it's because of what I went through as a parameter : backup.backupDB("bd_relatorios", "root", "", "C:/MudinhoX/Data/xd.sql");

Comment: I've edited my answer adding spaces on the *executeCmd*. Try with that, and also, use this path instead: "C:\\MudinhoX\\Data\\xd.sql"

Comment: Now add everything to the array, but keep going to the else.

Comment: What is the output when you run it? Add a screenshot to your post

Comment: The output has no errors after  if (processComplete == 0) go to else: else {
             System.out.println("Could not create the backup");
         }

Comment: I've edited my answer in order to show the ProcessBuilder error

Comment: C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqldump.exe : unknown option '--add-drop-database ' this error

Comment: the problem was the spaces now i have this error permision;  C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqldump.exe : Can't create/write to file 'C:\MudinhoX\Data' (Errcode: 13 "Permission denied")